# get LastBuiltRevision for each scm involved in a pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline build clones 3 git repositories.  When I query the build via this snippet, I can get the lastBuiltRevision of the first git clone, but not any of the others.

The web UI shows all three, so I know they are present in the data

```
def getLastBuiltRevisionForBuild(def jobName, def buildNo) {
    def instance = Hudson.instance
    def job = instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
    def data = job.getBuild("${buildNo}").getAction(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class)
    return data.getLastBuiltRevision()
}
```

How can I obtain last built revision when I have multiple checkouts in my pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Not getAction but getActions to obtain the data object for each checkout.  Then we can use getRemoteUrls() to identify which to use - **clearly some error checking would be nice here**

```
def dumpLastBuiltRevisionsForMultipleRepositories(def jobName, def buildNo) {
    def instance = Hudson.instance
    def job = instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
    def build = job.getBuild("${buildNo}")
    for (def data in build.getActions(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class) ) {
        println data.getRemoteUrls()[0]
        println data.getLastBuiltRevision()
    }    
}
```